# Add a prefix for uploadify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

Well, I am using Uploadify in my website and its working fine. But this time i want to put a prefix for it!

I sent a POST request with uploadify to uploadify.php using this code

```js
var prefix = '<?php echo substr(md5('anytext' . time()), 0, 3);?>';
$("#theme_uploader").uploadify({
    'formData'      : {
        'prefix'     : prefix
    }
});
```

in uploadify.php i normally used `$_POST['prefix']` and attached it to the uploading path, Uploadify now works fine and adds a prefix for each and everyfile added.

**What is the problem then ?**

The problem is with the file check-exists.php, It will not have the POST request for the prefix, So it will not be able to catch if the file exists or not, because it will not check for the prefix.

I know its low percentage for a "Same file name" problem, But i want everything works 100%.

Comment: where is the `check-exists.php` file. why don't you pass the prefix to it?

Comment: check-exists.php file is in the same directory of uploadify, With uploadify.php and uploadify.swf, I cant pass the prefix to it because it gets called automatically by uploadify, So i cant call it myself.

Comment: if uplodify supports a feature called prefix where u can provide a prefix to your file why don't they pass that info to check-exist?

Comment: uploadify doesn't supports a feature called prefix, I am trying to add it myself!

Comment: then you will likely need to edit the code that calls check-exist and include the prefix.

Comment: And this is the problem :)